In a tree where each node value represents the number of its children, what is the parent node of the i-th child? the nodes are named in level order
A tree structure represents a hypothetical chain of processes as follows:
Every process has child processes The number of child processes is equal to the process number i.e.,
process number 3 has 3 child processes. The processes are named in level order, the root being 1, its child/children are named from 2, and so on.
For example, given processNumber 6, its parent is 3
     1
     |
     2
    / \
   3   4
  /|\
 5 6 7

I found this question and I was able to solve it using bfs or iteratively, however I was wondering if there exists a mathematical approach to it that would solve it in O(1) or O(height of the tree). Is there at least an equation for the number of nodes in each level?

If we look at the processes numbered $1, 2, \dots, n-1$, then together they have $1+2+\dots+(n-1) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ children, which are numbered $2, 3, \dots, \frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1$. The next $n$ processes after that have parent $n$. In other words, if $f(x) = \frac{x(x-1)}{2}+2$, then a process has parent $n$ if its number is at least $f(n)$, but less than $f(n+1)$.
To figure out which parent this is: given process $k$, we can solve the quadratic equation $f(x)=k$ and get $x = \frac{1 + \sqrt{8k-15}}{2}$. This is usually not an integer, but it is between $n$ and $n+1$, so we can find what $n$ is by rounding it down. In other words: the parent of process $k$ is the floor $$\left\lfloor \frac{1 + \sqrt{8k-15}}{2} \right\rfloor.$$
For example, when $k=6$, this expression is $\frac{1 + \sqrt{8\cdot 6-15}}{2}$ or $\frac{1+\sqrt{33}}{2}$, which is approximately $3.37228$; we round that down to $3$, so the parent of $6$ is $3$.
The problem of finding the number of nodes at a level is much harder. The answer is given in OEIS sequence A002658, and has the recursive formula $$a(n+1) = a(n)(a(0) + \dots + a(n-1)) + \frac{a(n)(a(n)+1)}{2}$$ with the initial conditions $a(0)=a(1)=1$. There is not a known closed form.
